# Entity Framework - Add Migration Creating For Entities In External Assembly

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I've been using Entity Framework Code First migrations for a while now, and like to think I know the fundamentals pretty well. However, yesterday I came across a rather odd issue which I can't seem to find a solution to.

I've added a reference to a DLL (third party - not developed by ourselves) which has some interfaces I need on my entities. The DLL contains a bunch of other things - such as some classes - which we don't need and aren't using.

Now with the reference, and implementing some of the interfaces - when I add a migration using the Add-Migration command, Entity Framework seems to pick up some of the classes in the DLL, and tries to create tables for them in the migration.

For example, I have a 'User' entity in my project. I have added a reference to ThirdParty.dll, which contains an IThirdPartyUser interface. The DLL also contains a UnusedClass, **which I am not using - it is not part of my context in any way**.

When I create a migration, I get code to create the database tables for UnusedClass. For example:

```
         CreateTable(
            "dbo.UnusedClass",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    RegistrationNumber = c.Int(),
                })
```

Now my theory is that this external assembly (incorrectly) has some dependency on Entity Framework - but I can't figure out why migrations is trying to generate database code for them - **especially as they are not part of my context**.

Anyone come across this before? I'm about to embark on a trial and error exercise to try and get to the bottom of the issue.

Comment: I think I've made some progress. Some of the unused classes have properties with 'ID' in their name, which I think Entity Framework is picking up as an entity using its conventions. I've the model to ignore the classes in question - but is there any way to exclude classes in an entire namespace/DLL, or turn off conventions in this way? Don't like the fact EF is looking at every class in every single DLL like this.

Answer (score 0):

EF should only pick up classes that are in the object graph originating at your DbContext - so, if class A is in your context, and class A has a property of type UnusedClass, EF will try to scaffold it.

You can add the [NotMappedAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to a property or class to have EF ignore it when generating its mapping.

Comment: That's what I thought - but these classes are NOT defined in my DbContext. Which is why I'm convinced there's something else going on inside the assembly. I don't have the source so I can't add the NotMappedAttribute (plus that would involve adding a reference to EF to the assembly, which seems a little wrong). I have used DbModelBuilder.Ignore<>() to ignore the classes in question for the time being.